# Node serialport not receiving data

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, serial-port

I have a RS422 serial device connected to my Windows PC via a USB to serial cable.
The cable has an integrated FTDI chip and I'm using the corresponding VCP drivers to interact with the device like a COM device (COM3 port).

[image]

When I check the data stream via a serial port monitor application, I am able to see the data stream I expect. Indicating the driver setup is correct.

[image]

I now wish to read the data into a NodeJS application using the serialport package.

```
const port = new SerialPort("COM3", {
    baudRate: 115000
});

const ByteLength = SerialPort.parsers.ByteLength
const parser = new ByteLength({ length: 8 })
port.pipe(parser)

parser.on('data', console.log)

port.on('readable', function () {
    console.log('Data:', port.read())
})

port.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Data:', data)
})
```

The problem is that none of the data reading functions are logging any result. The connection is opened but no data seems to be received. I tried with different types of parsers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by enabling dtr and rts

```
 port.on('open', function () {
     port.set({ dtr: true, rts: true });
 })
```